# GIS Draw a parabola flight path in kml for google earth

Tags: math, gis, kml, google-earth

I have to display flight paths on google earth and (still I got the exact flight plan path) want to show in a parabola way (markting side). From the taking off to the landing points.
Basically I'm looking for the math formula to calculate latlng point with altitudes to display the parabola path.

I see how to do the parabolic view with the altitude parameter. But there is less easy, how to get points on a path from two cordinates (start; end).

Thank you !

Comment: I assume you want the 3-dimensional flight path (x,y,z) or in spherical coords (theta,alpha,radius)? Also to generate a parabola (quadratic curve) you need at least three points (eg start, middle and end points).

Comment: He's probably assuming a particular value for gravity. That reduces the # of points needed to 2. (although for small distances there are 2 solutions, depending on whether the angle of launch is greater/less than 45degrees.)

Comment: Correction, you're right, it's 3 points (alternatively you need to know the velocity/angle of launch). But the horizontal and vertical components of ballistic flight can be assumed to be independent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I'm wrong about this, but if I remember my physics right, and if the distance between the two points is relatively small compared to the earth's radius, aside from altitude, the path will just follow a [great circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle).

If you write the coordinates as parametric equations as a function of time, you'd get:

```
gamma = v_horz/R * t
altitude = g * t * (T0 - t) / 2    
(where T0 = 2*v_vert/g = flight time, R = earth radius, g = earth's gravity) 
(vertical velocity = derivative of altitude = g/2*T0 - gt = v_vert - gt
```

where gamma = the angle along the great circle arc followed by the projectile. You know the beginning and endpoints, so you can use [spherical trigonometry](http://www.jqjacobs.net/astro/arc_form.html#formula) to figure out the arc distace G0 between start and endpoints. G0 = gamma at time T0 (when projectile lands). This tells you what omega_horz must be (= G0*R / T0).

You can then use spherical trigonometry again to figure out the lat/longitude at any point along the great circle. (use similar triangles -- it's too late in the day for my brain to work through the math properly, sorry)

assumptions:

A.

- distance between start/end points is small compared to earth's radius
- the flight in question is a ballistic trajectory (some mass M going up and down under the force of gravity alone, no thrust or lift)
- we're talking about the planet Earth so you can make certain assumptions for the radius and the force of gravity g
- ignore air resistance (good luck in real life)

OR

B.

- this is for marketing types so you just want something that looks parabolic, so just use the assumptions in A anyway

---

**EDIT:** See also these wikipedia articles on [projectile trajectories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile) and [great circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance).

Comment: yes. you are correct; I missed the fact that the question was answerable without clarifications.

Comment: Sorry to answer so lately since I see how fast you reply to my question.
We found a way to divide the path from two points in many points just say 20 and then for each point give an altitude (y) with y = x^2 ... and some trick to let it start from (0;0) and end (pointB;0).